How does KL divergence show up in these calculations?
I'm studying the denosing diffusion probabilistic models (DDPM) paper. The derivation of the reduced variance variational bound contains the following step:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{0:T})} \Big[ \log\frac{q(\mathbf{x}_T \vert \mathbf{x}_0)}{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_T)} + \sum_{t=2}^T \log \frac{q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)}{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert\mathbf{x}_t)} - \log p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_0 \vert \mathbf{x}_1) \Big ] \\ = \mathbb{E}_q [D_\text{KL}(q(\mathbf{x}_T \vert \mathbf{x}_0) \parallel p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_T)) + \sum_{t=2}^T D_\text{KL}(q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0) \parallel p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert\mathbf{x}_t)) - \log p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_0 \vert \mathbf{x}_1) ]
$$
I cannot figure out how the KL divergences appear in the second expression. It seems as if we are considering this to be true:
$$\log \frac{q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)}{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert\mathbf{x}_t)} = D_\text{KL}(q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0) \parallel p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \vert\mathbf{x}_t)) $$
This is obviously not the definition of KL divergence, so I'm probably missing something.

Does this help?

Not really. That one makes sense to me. The divergence is converted to the expectation of log ratio. Here, in the last equation I provided, it appears equal to just the log ratio (without expectation). There is maybe some "manipulation" with the outer expectation going on, which I fail to realize. But I think I've found the answer in these two https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/46566/deriving-elbo-for-diffusion-models?rq=1
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/653800/derivation-of-expectation-with-subscript
